# Eclipse Photon - wrong keyboard layout only for shortcut

Tags: eclipse, keyboard-shortcuts

Moving from Eclipse Oxygen (4.7), to Eclipse Photon (4.8) introduced a strange issue with wrong keyboard layout, only for the shortcut.

I mean, for instance:

- in any editor, typing <kbd>A</kbd> key is producing a 'A' letter, which is OK
- but using <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>, to select all, is NOT working, because it is regarded as a <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd> (i.e. keyboard layout regarded as Qwerty instead of Azerty here)

After analysis, I found various related bug report on Eclipse' Bugzilla:

- https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=531378
- https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=533395
- https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=61190

But, I still don't have any working workaround to use Eclipse Photon with the good keyboard layout for shortcuts (despite having removed ALL keyboard layouts, but the one wanted, on my OS => which is GNU/Linux Fedora 26, with Gnome Shell).

Acting, the bug fix is NOT embedded in the 2018-09 release, I moved back to my previous Eclipse Oxygen release, where the bug does not exist.

Do you know any way to have this bug fixed with Eclipse Photon release?

Comment: Have you tried the following workaround? https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=533395#c6 Does it work in [2018-12 M1](https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/release/2018-12/m1)?

Comment: Yes, like said: "despite having removed ALL keyboard layouts, but the one wanted"

Comment: Please check if the bug is fixed in [2018-12 M1](https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/release/2018-12/m1). If not, comment on the bug.

Comment: @howlger I just tested it; the bug does not exist anymore in this release.
Anyway, it doesn't answer to my initial question ...

Comment: You can either fix the bug yourself in Photon (which is no longer maintained), upgrade to the milestone pre-release 2018-12 M1 (which is what I would recommend), or wait until the final release 2018-12 on December 19.

Comment: Does anyone have a proper answer?

Comment: If you still have this issue, you are using a version that is outdated for quite some time.

Comment: I don't, It is only to enhance this Q/A.

Answer (score 1):

This is a **[known issue](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=533395) of Eclipse Photon (4.8)** (see [this comment for a workaround](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=533395#c6)). It has been fixed in the follow-up release Eclipse 2018-09 (4.9), on September 19, 2018.

Upgrade Eclipse to get the fix (e.g. by [enabling major upgrades](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53964503/6505250)).