# could not process the request to update the Eclipse marketplace

Tags: linux, eclipse, logging, ide, eclipse-marketplace

Where is the log file for:

> Your original request has been modified.   No updates found. Configure
>   available software sites to reach more content.   Unexpected
>   Error.  Could not process the request. Check the error log for
>   details.

[image: event]

I see session data:

> eclipse.buildId=4.11.0.I20190307-0500 java.version=11.0.3
>   java.vendor=Oracle Corporation BootLoader constants: OS=linux,
>   ARCH=x86_64, WS=gtk, NL=en_CA Framework arguments:  -product
>   org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product Command-line arguments:  -data
>   file:/home/thufir/eclipse-workspace/ -os linux -ws gtk -arch x86_64
>   -product org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product

[image: error log]

from the [fine](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSMKHH_9.0.0/com.ibm.etools.mft.doc/au16690_.htm) manual:

> To view the Eclipse error log:
>
> ```
> Switch to the Plug-in Development perspective.
> From the main menu, select Window > Show view > Other. Then select General > Error Log.
> ```

when updating the marketplace:

[image: marketplace]

Comment: Follow these steps: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53964503/6505250

Comment: ah, thanks, I'll give that a go.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue. The best way is to uninstall Eclipse from Ubuntu Software Center.

After that remove the hidden folder from the system using the following command on terminal

`rm -r ~/.eclipse`

And then reinstall Eclipse!!

Don't forget to mark all your installed extension in Eclipse as Favourite, so that you re-download them after re-installing the new Eclipse.

Comment: The additional step of `rm -r ~/.eclipse` was what finally cleared the old installation out for me. Without that, some old (troublesome, i.e. they refused to uninstall) versions of Egit were always reappearing (in the Marketplace) even after removing and then re-installing Eclipse (using only the **Ubuntu Software** application).