# how to get Eclipse to correctly open a gradle project?

Tags: eclipse, gradle, kotlin, gradle-kotlin-dsl, eclipse-marketplace

Both Kotlin and Gradle [installed](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58262777/262852) fine through the marketplace:

[image: market]

And I've right [clicked](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17907927/262852) the project "refresh dependencies" from the Gradle context menu:

[image: project]

what else can I do to get Eclipse to [load](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58262546/262852) this project?  Despite the errors from Eclipse, it runs fine from the console:

```
thufir@dur:~/eclipse-workspace/baseX$ 
thufir@dur:~/eclipse-workspace/baseX$ gradle clean run

> Task :run
Oct. 06, 2019 7:58:19 P.M. org.basex.examples.local.LoadXML <init>
INFO: {databaseName=books, dataResource=books.xml}
Oct. 06, 2019 7:58:20 P.M. org.basex.examples.local.LoadXML createDrop
INFO: Name   Resources  Size  Input Path  
----------------------------------
books  0          4570              

1 database(s).


BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 1s
4 actionable tasks: 4 executed
thufir@dur:~/eclipse-workspace/baseX$
```

Comment: Which errors? The question is tagged with Kotlin but the question does not even mention Kotlin. Please show a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: kotlin in that it's using the kotlin DSL, it's reproducible by creating the project with gradle commands.  Else, not sure what Eclipse needs as it would seem to have the necessary pieces (gradle and kotln).