# No tests found with test runner 'junit4'

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium, junit4, java-11

I had an already working JUnit4 Selenium test enviroment. After I switched from Java 8 to 11 eclipse doesn't always find my tests anymore. I can fix it eventually, but it always takes time. Can you help me fix it?

Every test has an `@Test` Annotation and the test project worked for years without those problems. My Folder structure is like:

```
ProjectName/src/test/java/testPackage/testClass.java
```

If eclipse doesn't find the tests I'm using the following options which seem all sometimes to work and sometimes not:

1. restarting Eclipse
2. rebuilding project
3. renaming some test with a prefix "test" ~ I know, crazy.
4. reloading all test files in eclipse [F5]
5. changing the Run Configuraion source folder to `src/test/java`.

All those "solutions" aren't always helping and I have to try around to find the one that helps. But I can fix it eventually.

Does anyone have a solution that always fixes that kind of problem?
Or even better, is there a solution to fix it permanently?

Comment: Can you share us more informations like your runner classes?

Comment: I didn't specify any runner class, so I'm using the JUnit4 default runner.

Comment: Is your features are defined under RunCukes or your current runner?

Comment: I don't use RunCukes. I just use ProjectName->run as->JUnit Test with my JUnit4. And with Java 8 it never had any problems. With Java 11 it does somehow. I didn't change the eclipse version [2018-12 (4.10.0)]

Comment: Sorry Joshua I thought it was about cucumber.

Comment: Do you have main method inside of your test classes?

Comment: No I don't have a main method

Comment: Your Eclipse is outdated, you are 3 releases behind. Can you reproduce the issue with the [current Eclipse version 2019-09 (4.13)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53964503/6505250)?

Comment: I will try it tomorrow, thanks for your help already.